# Definining and processing configuration values with Config Component

Tags: symfony

Im trying to expose some configurations for my bundle that allows the user to define an entity name and multiple associations between a property and a value. Basically for each entity the user can define the sort and order fields. For example:
For entity AcmeDemoBundle:Project, I want to sort by "name DESC" and "id ASC"

```
acme_demo_default_sort:
    entities:
        AcmeDemoBundle:Project:
            - 
                property: name
                order: desc
            -
                property: id
                order: asc
```

OR

```
acme_demo_default_sort:
    entities:
        AcmeDemoBundle:Project:
           name: desc
           id: asc
```

How can I parse the treebuilder for the above configurations?

Im able to achive a similar solution with the example below:

```
acme_demo_default_sort:
    entities:
        AcmeDemoBundle:Project:
            defaults:
                - 
                    property: name
                    order: desc


$rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('entities')                    
                    ->prototype('array')
                        ->children()    
                            ->arrayNode('defaults')
                                ->prototype('array')
                                    ->children()
                                        ->scalarNode('property')->end()
                                        ->scalarNode('order')->end()
                                    ->end()
                                ->end()
                            ->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use the solution with the defaults?

Comment: Because its cleaner without the defaults key.